# Blazor input select databind with nullable type and default value

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a `Guid?` bound to a `<select>`, and since this type is nullable, I want it to show the "All" option value when there is no value in the property.

I tried this without success:

```
<select @bind="MyLocalParameter">
    <option value="">All</option>
    @foreach (var item in Items)
    {
        <option value="@item.IdGuid">@item.Name</option>
    }
</select>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: It's not a good solution, but the only solution I've been able to find for this in Blazor is to do something like set your All option value to `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` and then check for that instead of null to show all.

Comment: Really @Kyle? this is bad..... :(

Comment: Can you share more of your code? Maybe in a BlazorFiddle? What else have you tried and what was the result?

Comment: It's very simple @JasonShave-MSFT: when the user selects the "All" value, I want Blazor to set the the property `MyLocalParameter` to null. In the above code, it's not possible to select the "All" option, Blazor doesn't allow.

Comment: Ya, very odd. It doesn't look like the option tag can contain a null value. Have a test drive here: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/1m1clsb6